# angularjs error defining a controller

Tags: angularjs

After reading some of the tutorials I structured my app such that there is a controllers & services module which were dependencies of the app.  I would get the controllers module call dot controller on it to create a new controller.  I have done this with some of my code and it works.  I tried adding another controller and the same code is not working.  Can anyone tell me why the section of code below doesn't work for adding a controller.

```
// ffpApp.js 
ffpApp = angular.module("ffpApp",
            ['ngRoute',
             'ffpControllers',
             'ffpServices']);

 /* Controllers */
 var ffpControllers = angular.module('ffpControllers', []);

 /* Services */
 var ffpServices = angular.module('ffpServices', ['rails']);
```

This is the file where I am defining my controller.

```
// createnew_controller.js 

'use strict';

/* Controllers */
var ffpControllers = angular.module('ffpControllers');

//
// This section of code works.
//
angular.module('ffpApp').controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    console.log("hello world");
}]);


//
// This section FAILS; argument not a function got Undefined when
// trying to use it in ffpApp.js
//
ffpControllers.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    console.log("hello world");
}]);
```

Comment: There does not seem to be any error in the pasted code. You are probably missing some relevant information. What do you mean by `trying to use it in ffpApp.js` use what?

Comment: I am trying to use it when I define a route and specify the controller name.

Answer (score 0):

The controller you have working was added to the module called 'ffpApp' i.e. the main App module NOT to the dedicated controllers module.
Both controllers have got the same name i.e. 'MyController'.

The code:

```
var ffpControllers = angular.module('ffpControllers');
```

is creating another module the same name as your main App module but with no dependencies. This code needs to be removed.

Try the following method. Make sure the files are included in your index.html file.

APP.JS

```
/*================================================================
Module - main App module 
dependencies injected include the controllers module and services module
=================================================================*/
angular.module("ffpApp", ['ngRoute', 'ffpControllers', 'ffpServices']);
```

CONTROLLERS.JS

```
/*================================================================
Module - Just for Controllers
Define your controllers in this file also
=================================================================*/
angular.module('ffpControllers', [])

//Controller 1
.controller('MyController1', function ($scope) {
    console.log("hello from controller 1");
})

//Controller 2
.controller('MyController2', function ($scope) {
    console.log("hello from controller 2");
});
```

SERVICES.JS

```
/*================================================================
Module - Just for Services
Define your services in this file below the module
=================================================================*/
angular.module('ffpServices', []);
```